# Can I trigger assignment rules when a case is updated from a lightning record page without using Apex or Process Builder?

Tags: assignment-rules

For page layouts in Salesforce classic, I can use the checkbox 'Case Assignment Checkbox' option in the layout properties. But for lightning pages, I could not find any such option. Is it there, or any alternative to that? Or is my only option is to use Apex/Process Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the Spring 17 Release Notes:

> Support agents now can see the Case Assignment checkbox on new cases
>   in Lightning Experience. This change applies to Lightning Experience
>   only. Previously, the Case Assignment Checkbox wasn’t visible in
>   Lightning Experience. To allow agents to trigger assignment rules
>   manually when cases are created or edited, add the Case Assignment
>   checkbox to the case layout page.

[Case Assignment Checkbox Visible in Lightning Experience](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_cases_assignment_rules.htm)

Comment: This is for new cases. But this is not visible while updating cases. I want to trigger assignment rules when cases are updated.

Comment: in that case @SagnikChattopadhyay you will atleast need process builder.